# UTF8 woes with mysql/php

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8, character-encoding

I've got a mysql table with some imported data, in particular one value is `Sinn Féin`.

The character set used for my database is `utf8_general_ci`. The data displays fine in phpMyAdmin. In my site, I've used the PHP header `header("Content-type: text/html; charset='utf-8'");`. I've got `<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />` in my `<head>`.

My data still comes up as `Sinn F�in`. I've tried using `utf8_decode`, but that doesn't help. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you checked that the charset of the table is the same? Is your PHP file encoded in UTF-8?

Comment: Are you setting the db connection collation to UTF-8 as well as the table storage itself?

Comment: @liquorvicar I don't think so, how do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Аfter `mysql_connect()` add this line:

```
mysql_query ("SET NAMES utf8");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

> $dbc="database connection";
>
> mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8",$dbc);